# run a php script with cron that schedules events

Tags: php, date, scheduler

I am trying to run a different script on the  three different time of the month, every day, every Monday and the first Monday of the month, I have put together the following with help from people on here, cron will run this once a day and the corresponding scripts will get run at the pre set times.

Is there anyway I can test the following other than putting it on the server and waiting for the selected dates ?, I am running a local apache server, if I change the date on that to the first day of the month and run it, would this be ok ?.

Is this all correct ? :

```
<?php
$RUN_everyday = `/path/to/php/everyday.php`;
$RUN_everymonday = `/path/to/php/everymonday.php`;
$RUN_firstmondayofmonth = `/path/to/php/firstmondayofmonth.php`;


date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$weekday = date('D');
$dayOfMonth = date('d');
// runs the everyday php file
echo '$RUN_everyday';
if ($weekday == 'Mon')
{
//runs the every monday php file every monday of the week
echo '$RUN_everymonday';
if ($dayOfMonth <=6)
//runs the first monday of the month php file on the first monday of each month
echo '$RUN_mondayofmonth';
}
?>
```

Comment: Am I getting your idea right that you use cron to trigger the execution of this script? And this script itself should trigger three other scripts? Why don't you use cron directly to trigger the three scripts? As it is very intuitive then I would also say that no heavy testing of the cron settings is needed.

Comment: `if ($dayOfMonth <=6)` should actually be `if ($dayOfMonth <=7)`. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd test it by just manually setting those variables:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
//$weekday = date('D');
//$dayOfMonth = date('d');
$weekday = 4;      // <-----------
$dayOfMonth = 14;  // <-----------
// runs the everyday php file
echo '$RUN_everyday';
```

Change that to whatever values you want to test and trigger it - see what happens!

Comment: thanks :-) , it seems to be ok by the look of it when I tried it

Comment: Also, I didn't notice your username. Snap. Ian Simpson, at your service ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the tool that almost everybody uses for this type of job: cron.

Comment: how do I check to see if a client is a member of the every monday group and if they are send them the prices ?

Comment: You'd write that logic in the script that cron would call.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't add the layer of php to do this.  Cron can handle this sort of scheduling on its own.

This should do it:

```
0 0 * * * php every_day_midnight.php
0 0 * * 1 php every_monday_midnight.php
0 0 0-6 * 1 php first_monday_midnight.php
```