# How to send request from php automatically everyday/week

Tags: php

i have a problem, if I have a function in php and i want to run it for send request automatically everyday/week, how can I do that? 
I do not have any ideas for that

any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Luckily the internet is a treasure trove of ideas

Comment: `cron` is what you are looking for. It is a service of linux-based operating system that allows you to run your PHP script at predefined times/intervals. Also hosting companies usually support setting cron jobs from their administration interfaces. And for Windows-based servers, you would be looking for `Task Scheduler`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run a php script with cron that schedules events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781760/run-a-php-script-with-cron-that-schedules-events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use crons for this purpose. You can schedule a PHP file to be run on a particular time/day/date/interval as per your needs.

You can refer to [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800) for details on how to schedule a cron.